# Windows Form Localization

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

I'm trying to get localization to work in my application. I can follow the typical example online and get it to work in a sample project. (ie. setting the Localizable property and the cultures).

When I try to use it in my application, it always uses the default resource file no matter what language I choose.

EDIT: If I go to the properties of my startup project, select Debug, and set the Start Action to Start Project, it will work. If I run the executable that gets created when building by selecting it in "Start external program", it will not work. Any idea why?

EDIT: When I use the Start External Program, the executable I am pointing to is not pointing to the bin/Debug folder of the project. I have a post build event to copy it elsewhere and am pointing to that. Because of this, maybe it is not able to see the reference files that are in the Debug folder?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: 1. Did you try to use a MessageBox to see if at least the CultureInfo was getting updated? 2. I got confused a little bit, is the application (which you're having this problem with) *the* Windows Application? 3. Are you applying the resources accordingly?

Comment: 1. Debugging the program I can see that the currentculture does get set to fr-CA. 2. I'm having the problem in a class library, though I have referenced the library in the main application and it did not work there either. I'm not sure what you mean by question #3

Comment: Pretty difficult to put these tiny slivers of code into anything that yells "bug".  If you want to test what a French Canadian sees then just do what he does.  Tell the operating system that you speak French.  Control Panel + Language.

Comment: Right now the French Canadian resource file is basically the same form. I just changed a label's text slightly so that I could confirm or deny that the correct resource file is being used. Unfortunately, the correct resource file is not being used. The issue is likely a property or some nuance that I don't know about. The code itself completely checks out compared to the sample project that works. I just don't know know else would effect this. For example, if you have the neutral language set to us-EN and you have a us-EN resource file, it will use the default resource instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you localize a form, it creates a folder per language in the build's output path that holds a resource file projectname.resources.dll.

I have a post build command that puts our .dlls elsewhere. I needed to change the command to also push out the resource files so that they were in the same directory. Once I did this, I was able to get it to work.